# Run puppeteer on Netlify Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, puppeteer, netlify

I try to use Puppeteer in a function on Netlify (a wrapper around AWS Lambda I think). The function builds but when I visit the url I get this error: "Error: Chromium revision is not downloaded. Run "npm install" or "yarn install""

I'm not sure what the problem is, but if I run the function locally with `node index.js` it runs without problem.

The function:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let browser;
let page;


exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
  await setup();
  await snap('http://example.org', 'file.png');

  browser.close();
  console.log('Done!');
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: 'OK',
  };
};

async function setup() {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1024, height: 512 });
}

async function snap(url, file) {
  try {
    console.log('snapping :', url);
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.screenshot({ path: file, type: 'png' });
    console.log('snapped :', file);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log('err :', err);
  }
}
```

Comment: In your netlify function, puppeteer is trying to download chrome; but you cannot download such big things on aws lambda, you need to bundle a headless version and upload it along with your package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have any resources on this?

Answer (score 0):

Netlify functions are indeed powered by AWS Lambda and are subject to the AWS Lambda limits. [Deployment package size is limited to 50 MB (zipped)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) which is below what is required by Puppeteer.

That said, as mentioned on the [Puppeteer GitHub troubleshooting page](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-on-aws-lambda), workarounds are available. You could for instance use this Chromium binary: https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda.